# .pl what does it stand for?

Tags: sql, insert-into

I have a code with ".pl" is this referencing to  a proprietary procedural language used by Oracle?

The SQL code is below

```
insert into ueb03.pl   
(select p.pk_punkt ,l.pk_linie as linie from ueb03.Punkt as p, ueb03.linie as l   
where ST_intersects (p.geom,l.geom));
```

Comment: Isn't `ueb03` the schema name?

Comment: Depends on DB. Usually  `ueb03` is treated as schema name and `pl` as table name.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the table is [unquoted](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223), that's a [fully qualified table name](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements009.htm).

Comment: (Answer and links specifically refer to Oracle based on my initial reading of his question.  If he's not using Oracle I'll delete this.)